# Upgrading CentOS 6.7 to CentOS 7 on VMWare 11.0

Tags: centos, upgrade, x86

I tried to upgrade(in-place) CentOS 6.7 to CentOS 7.0 on the various environments.

I installed CentOS-6.7-x86_64-bin-DVD1.iso on VWware 11.0.
And I followed the https://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/CentOSUpgradeTool.
When I run the preupg, I got the following results.

**"We found some potential in-place upgrade risks."**

[image]

And then I continued to work the upgrading.

But after completeing the upgrade I can't start due to kernel panic or login to system.

Please tell me the reason.

**I expected that the minimal system of CentOS 6.7 will be upgrading successfully and I installed CentOS-6.7-x86_64-minimal.iso and tried to upgrade, but I failed.**

My questions:

1. The command *preupg* and *redhat-upgrade-tool* are not yet completed?
2. The upgrading on CentOS is not recommended? If so, Why?
3. The upgrading on RHEL 6.7 is woring well?(I have no RHEL 6.7)

Comment: Did you read `/root/preupgrade/result.html` as the message tells you to do?

Answer (score 2):

1. Originally, the tool worked when we were at the GA release of RHEL 7 (7.0). At this point, it does not.
2. It is absolutely **not** recommended. You are better off doing a clean installation at all times. This involves taking a backup of what's necessary (such as static web content, etc), installing the system, and restoring from backup.
3. Their tools are broken as well. This is primarily because there are versions of some packages in EL6 that are a newer version than EL7. This breaks the core pieces of the system.

Comment: I don't think this is true. RHEL upgrade tool should work between releases 6 and 7 regardless minor versions. Not sure about CentOS, if they break something?

Answer (score 0):

Official page says that tool is broken for Centos 6.7, form more information read this https://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/CentOSUpgradeTool